# how to check response start and response end in python program when calling from php

Tags: php, python

I need to run python program from PHP.I have plan of using this sample code.

```
<?php
exec("python yelp_feeder.py", $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

I just want to find response from python program.When it start executes I want to show some progress bar till it get completed.Once it completed,I want to remove the progress bar and make the output to display.

Hope it give sense.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe accept some of the answers to your other questions. You will see a grayed check mark to the left of each response by the up/down arrows. Click it to mark it accepted.